# Use GeoServer as source of vector layer in OpenLayers 3

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs

I am using PostGIS and GeoServer and OpenLayers 3 (OL3). I connected PostGIS table to GeoServer and published my layer.  I am using following code to get the layer as vector layer:

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/geoserver/cite/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=cite:myfeaturesTbl&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application/json&'
    })
});
```

I need to read my feature as vector layer because I want to select them and then get information of each feature or move them on the map. When I use this code it is not show anything.

Is there any problem in my code?

Can you help me get a vector layer in OL3 with a GeoServer WFS?

Comment: Try the "Layer Preview" in GeoServer, and tell us if the layer works there. Also, is the client really running on the same machine (localhost) as GeoServer?

Comment: Hello, Yes layer Preview shows the layer. also I can show the layer with WMS. also Geoserver and client in are in same machine. I wanna know how can I show a layer (vector layer), from geoserver with OL3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem lies in your use of `url`, which in OL3 seems to expect only *static files*, i.e. `url = "/static/data/geojson.json"`.

To fill your map with dynamically loaded data use ajax calls and the `ol.source.Vector.addFeatures` method:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.GeoJSON({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326'
}),

$.get(
    '/geoserver/cite/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=cite:myfeaturesTbl&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application/json'
    // success callback 
    function (data) {
        // first add features  
        vectorSource.addFeatures(vectorSource.readFeatures(data));

        // then display map...
        var map = new ol.Map({
                                target: '...',
                                layers: [
                                    new ol.layer.Tile({
                                        source: ...
                                    }),
                                    new ol.layer.Vector({  
                                        source: vectorSource 
                                    })
       });
   }
);
```